# Xamarin Studio - Application not launching in simulator

Tags: xamarin

I am new to Xamarin and i am trying to the sample app "XamarinStone". I can see the emulator is launching, but the application is not loading.

I kept at the same state for 1 hour, but still no hope.

I tried with Visual Studio 2012, but I am facing the same issue.

i installed all the necessary applications as per Xamarin Installer. What else I would need to do?

Can anyone help me to troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm that you've setup Xamarin latest version in both Windows & Mac PC?

And as per below screenshot of Visual Studio, you see list of iPhone Simulators?

And as per the second highlighted image "Show iOS Simulator" button, when you click on that image, it invokes iOS simulator on your MAC?

[image]